# Searching a file for unknown integer with minimum memory requirement

Tags: java, algorithm

A Senior student asked me this question, probably was an interview question.But still how can we do it?

The question:

*Given an i/p file with 4 billion integers produce a integer that doesnt exist in the file given u have only 10 mb memory*

Comment: So there are 294967296 missing integers (assuming by integer you mean the standard 32-bit int type)? Is there a runtime requirement? If multiple passes are allowed this is quite easy.

Comment: are **O(n^2)** solutions fine?

Comment: @SamIam Knowing that n = 4,000,000,000?  Your question would raise a flag during an interview…

Comment: if you have enough external storage, just sort the numbers, then iterate over until you find a gap